# Cross-compiling application and gcc using headers wrong headers

Tags: c, linux, gcc, cross-compiling

I'm attempting to cross-compile for an arm7 board using a toolchain on x86-64 Ubuntu. The headers I need are on the filesystem here:

```
.../include/<libdir1>
.../include/<libdir2>
[more]
.../include/<libdirN>
```

but the .../include directory contains incompatible standard headers (for reasons I can't control). Using -I option causes gcc to use these incompatible standard headers rather than the ones it should. Including all the compatible standard header paths with -I options prior to this also does not work.

I want to use the same source paths for when I'm compiling natively and also for the arm7 board:

```
#include <libdir1/lib1.h>
#include <libdir2/lib2.h>
...
#include <libdirN/libN.h>
```

Is there a way to do this using the filesystem as it currently exists or do I need to copy the lib1, lib2, ... libN header files somewhere else entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [-iquote](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html) option for this:

> Add the directory dir to the head of the list of directories to be searched for header files only for the case of `#include "file"'; they are not searched for`#include ', otherwise just like -I.

So you would include your custom headers with `""` style include directives:

```
#include "libdir1/lib1.h"
#include "libdir2/lib2.h"
```

But the standard headers with `<>` style:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

And then add the directory with `-iquote` rather than `-I`:

```
-iquote../include
```