# GCC confusing standard header with personal one named the same

Tags: c, gcc, include

In a project I'm working on, I named one of my files `math.h`, which obvisouly is also the name of a [standard library header](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/math.h).

Everything worked fine, until I began to use gcc's `-I` option: I sorted my files into separate directories, like `src`, `obj` and `inc` for headers.

I ended up with something like

```
gcc ... -Iinc/
```

and now my issue is that another library I use (the [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org), btw) `#include`s the *standard* math.h header (located at `/usr/include/math.h`), and GCC gives it my own math.h (found at like `/home/me/my_project/inc/math.h`), and obviously this does not compile.

So my question is, how can I make GCC not think my headers are standard?
Of course I can just rename the file, but that would just be avoiding the issue -- even if I end up doing so I wish to know the solution in case I come across this issue again.

Comment: Why do you think the proper solution is not to rename the file? If there are multiple files with the same name, how would the compiler know which one to use?

Comment: One way to "rename" a file is to put it in a subdirectory. When you include <myproject/math.h>, that doesn't get confused with <math.h>. But you will have to rename one way or another, any other solution would be a fragile hack.

Comment: Don't name your files with names of [standard headers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/header). You really don't want to confuse your reader (perhaps yourself, in a few months). You should try to write *readable* code. So rename your `math.h` as `jo_math.h` or some other distinctive name

Comment: "Doctor, Doctor! It hurts when I do this..."

Answer (score 6):

You **must** rename your file. The C11 standard says that in the current state the behaviour is undefined. [C11 7.1.2p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.2p3)

> 3. If a file with the same name as one of the above `<` and `>` delimited sequences, not provided as part of the implementation, is placed in any of the standard places that are searched for included source files, the **behavior is undefined.**

---

Otherwise, if you're compiling a kernel or similar, use `-ffreestanding`.

Comment: Well if the standard says so... I just don't understand the *not provided as part of the implementation* part. Id do provide the source for the header, right? Unless they mean the standard header?

Comment: @joH1 it means *your `math.h` file*.  It is not provided as part of an implementation (of the compiler and standard library), and it is stored in a place that is searched for included source files (i.e. thanks to `-I`), and its name matches a `<` and `>` delimited sequence from the list above, namely `<math.h>`.

Comment: OK ! Thanks, and +1 for the work. Anyway I found [somewhere else](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15255558/6337519) a trick that works: using `-iquote` instead of `-I`. It may just be a GCC extension though.

Comment: Both of them are GCC extensions. I still would just rename the file. But yeah, that would change it so that your directory isn't one of those where the `<math.h>` would be looked up. You can add it as an answer.

Comment: Another (and perhaps the most important) reason to avoid having a header simply given as `"math.h"` is that you don't want to confuse the reader.

Comment: `-I` is specified by POSIX. `-iquote` is gcc-defined.